# My Ubuntu doesn't start. What happen?

Tags: boot

This morning my Ubuntu doesn't start. Why?

[This Is the Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0Jyulje_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** reboot computer and spam the 'SHIFT' button until you see GRUB bootloader
you will see:
**2)** advanced options -> recovery mode generic 
**3)** boot into recovery mode
**4)** run fsck from there and pkg repair.
**5)** continue normal boot from the same menu
see if that helps